# Android NativeAppInstallAdView never shows the ad

Tags: android, admob

I have a problem with showing native app install ad view in one of my activities. As Google shows the implementation of native ads on: 
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/NativeExample I have integrated the code to my project. Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.somepack.tests"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And I have also added same code to my root gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried to run the app with Google's app id and unit id, and everything seems to be working. When I change app id and unit id to my values, it just keeps saying 'Failed to load native ad' with the error code 0.

And here is my activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdLoader;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAppInstallAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAppInstallAdView;

import java.util.List;

public class AdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ad);

        String ADMOB_APP_ID = getString(R.string.admob_app_id);
        // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(this, ADMOB_APP_ID);
        refreshAd();
    }

    private AdRequest.Builder getBuilder() {
        AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            builder.addTestDevice("BDFA4B1F1E11FDA72D43368841CF0E04");
        }
        return builder;
    }

    private void refreshAd() {
        AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, getString(R.string.admob_unit_id));
        builder.forAppInstallAd(new NativeAppInstallAd.OnAppInstallAdLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAppInstallAdLoaded(NativeAppInstallAd ad) {
                FrameLayout frameLayout =
                        (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl_adplaceholder);
                NativeAppInstallAdView adView = (NativeAppInstallAdView) getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.ad_app_install, null);
                populateAppInstallAdView(ad, adView);
                frameLayout.removeAllViews();
                frameLayout.addView(adView);
            }
        });

        AdLoader adLoader = builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Toast.makeText(AdActivity.this, "Failed to load native ad: "
                        + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).build();

        adLoader.loadAd(getBuilder().build());
    }

    private void populateAppInstallAdView(NativeAppInstallAd nativeAppInstallAd,
                                          NativeAppInstallAdView adView) {
        adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_headline));
        adView.setImageView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_image));
        adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_body));
        adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_call_to_action));
        adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_app_icon));
        adView.setPriceView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_price));
        adView.setStarRatingView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_stars));
        adView.setStoreView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_store));

        // Some assets are guaranteed to be in every NativeAppInstallAd.
        ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getHeadline());
        ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getBody());
        ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getCallToAction());
        ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(nativeAppInstallAd.getIcon()
                .getDrawable());

        List<NativeAd.Image> images = nativeAppInstallAd.getImages();

        if (images.size() > 0) {
            ((ImageView) adView.getImageView()).setImageDrawable(images.get(0).getDrawable());
        }

        // Some aren't guaranteed, however, and should be checked.
        if (nativeAppInstallAd.getPrice() == null) {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getPriceView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getPrice());
        }

        if (nativeAppInstallAd.getStore() == null) {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getStore());
        }

        if (nativeAppInstallAd.getStarRating() == null) {
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView())
                    .setRating(nativeAppInstallAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Assign native ad object to the native view.
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAppInstallAd);
    }
}
```

I thought it doesn't show the ad because my apk is debug and tried with release too. But no chance. Am I missing a setting on Admob panel or any code that I need to implement? I am greatly appriciated for any help.

P.S: The code I wrote above is just a trial, I have the same code in my real app, which is on Play Store, but could not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible you're requesting Native Advanced ads from an ad unit that can't serve them. Have you and your app been accepted into the beta for AdMob's Native Ads Advanced? If not, you won't be able to create a Native Advanced ad unit, which means the code you provided above will only work in test mode.

Right now AdMob offers two different kinds of native ads, Advanced and Express (there's [a guide that explains the difference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native)). Native Express is newer, easier, and open to all AdMob publishers, so if you haven't tried it yet, I'd suggest giving it a look:

- [Native Ads Express guide for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express)
- [Native Express sample for Android](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/NativeExpressExample)

Comment: Hey @RedBrogdon, thanks for your comment. I have tried both native express and advanced ads with the same key, but could not get it work.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend posting this on the SDK support forum for AdMob. The support staff there can get more info from you and see what's going on: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/google-admob-ads-sdk/android